# How to prove this integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have this exercise : let $f(X): [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that $ 0< m \le f(x) \le M < \infty $ a.e. Prove that

$$\big( \int_0^1 f(x) dx \Big) \big( \int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(x)} dx \Big) \le \frac{(M+m)^2}{4mM} .$$

My attempt: I tried to divide the interval $[0,1]$ in thwo sets $A=\{x\in [0,1] | f(x) \le \sqrt{Mm}\}$ and $B=[0,1] \setminus A$. Called $x$ the measure of $B$, i get that the first integral is less than
$$xM+(1-x)\sqrt{Mm}$$
and the second integral is less than
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{Mm}}+\frac{(1-x)}{m}.$$
Taking the product of these two quantities and maximize for $x \in [0,1]$ I get a value (always when $x=1/2$ ) of
$$ \frac{(\sqrt{M}+\sqrt{m})^2}{4m}.$$ This is similar but not exactly the bound the exercise asks to find.

Comment: What if you replace $\sqrt{Mn}$ by $\frac{M+m}{2}$?

Comment: That was my first try, but I get always a trivial maximum at $x=0$ of $M/m$.

Answer (score 2):

Taking inspiration from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3231687/66096), note that $x\in [m,M]\implies x+\frac{mM}x \leq m+M$, thus $$f+\frac{mM}{f}\leq m+M$$

Integrating, $\int_0^1 f(x) dx +mM \int_0^1 \frac 1{f(x)}dx \leq m+M$ and by AM-GM
$$\sqrt{\int_0^1 f(x) dx \cdot mM \int_0^1 \frac 1{f(x)}dx}\leq \frac 12 \left( \int_0^1 f(x) dx +mM \int_0^1 \frac 1{f(x)}dx\right)\le \frac{m+M}2 $$

Hence $$\int_0^1 f(x) dx \cdot \int_0^1 \frac 1{f(x)}dx \leq \frac{(m+M)^2}{4mM}$$